# How can I construct a confidence interval for the age dependency ratio?

Tags: confidence-interval, delta-method, demography

Say I have a simple random sample of people from a given country, and I estimate the elderly dependency ratio in the population by taking the ratio of the number of people aged 65+ over the number aged 15-64 in my sample.  Besides bootstrap or jackknife resampling, how can I construct a confidence interval around this estimate?

I thought that perhaps I could use the multivariate delta method to estimate the sampling distribution of this dependency ratio, but my attempt to apply the multivariate delta method as described on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#Multivariate_delta_method) to some simulated data yielded a much larger estimated confidence interval than the one I obtained using a bootstrap approach.  I'm not sure if that is because I screwed up my implementation of the multivariate delta method, or if it is because that method does not apply here. I've included my R simulation code below in case it is helpful.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(purrr)

# set seed
set.seed(2019 - 9 - 3)

# Functions
elderly_dep_ratio <- function(df) {
  mean(df$elderly) / mean(df$working_age)
}

sample_variance_of_elderly_dep_ratio <- function(sample_df) {
  n <- nrow(sample_df)
  ppn_elderly <- mean(sample_df$elderly)
  ppn_working_age <- mean(sample_df$working_age)
  cov_mtrx <- cov_mtrx_of_multinom_ppns(ppn_elderly, ppn_working_age, n)
  gradient <- gradient_of_p1_over_p2(ppn_elderly, ppn_working_age)
  t(gradient) %*% cov_mtrx %*% gradient / n
}

se_of_elderly_dep_ratio <- function(sample_df) {
  sqrt(sample_variance_of_elderly_dep_ratio(sample_df))
}

variance_of_ppn <- function(p, n) {
  (p * (1 - p)) / n
}

covariance_of_multinom_ppns <- function(p1, p2, n) {
  -n * p1 * p2
}

gradient_of_p1_over_p2 <- function(p1, p2) {
  matrix(
    c(1 / p2, -p1 / p2 ^ 2),
    ncol = 1
  )
}

cov_mtrx_of_multinom_ppns <- function(p1, p2, n) {
  matrix(
    c(variance_of_ppn(p1, n), covariance_of_multinom_ppns(p1, p2, n),
      covariance_of_multinom_ppns(p1, p2, n), variance_of_ppn(p2, n)),
    ncol = 2,
    byrow = TRUE
  )
}

# Simulation
d <- tibble(age = sample(0:100, 1e5, replace = TRUE))

d <- d %>% 
  mutate(
    working_age = age %in% 15:64,
    youth = age %in% 0:14,
    elderly = age %in% 65:100
  )

sample_of_d <- sample_n(d, 1000)

## True elderly dependency ratio
elderly_dep_ratio(d)
#> [1] 0.7244615

## Sample elderly dependency ratio
elderly_dep_ratio(sample_of_d)
#> [1] 0.6474104

## Bootstrap approach
bootstrapped_estimates <- map_dbl(
  1:1000,
  ~ sample_of_d %>% 
    sample_n(1000, replace = TRUE) %>% 
    elderly_dep_ratio()
)
quantile(bootstrapped_estimates, probs = c(0.025, 0.975))
#>      2.5%     97.5% 
#> 0.5646303 0.7440998

## Multivariate delta method approach
delta_method_se <- se_of_elderly_dep_ratio(sample_of_d)
c(
  elderly_dep_ratio(sample_of_d) - 1.96 * delta_method_se,
  elderly_dep_ratio(sample_of_d) + 1.96 * delta_method_se
)
#> [1] -1.147121  2.441942
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Update**

I think I got the multivariate delta method estimates to agree more closely with the bootstrapped estimates by making one correction to the code above. In the function `sample_variance_of_elderly_dep_ratio()`, instead of computing the covariance matrix with the function `cov_mtrx_of_multinom_ppns()`, I changed to estimating the covariance from the sample data: `cov_mtrx <- cov(select(sample_df, elderly, working_age))`.

The function `cov_mtrx_of_multinom_ppns()` was based on the well known formula for the variance of a proportion and a formula for the covariance of two proportions from [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1007.5953&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper.

Even though I think I now have the implementation of the multivariate delta method basically right, I'd still be interested in feedback on why my initial approach didn't work.

Comment: What is the elderly dependency ratio?  We need more information and less code.

Comment: The elderly dependency ratio is the proportion of people aged 65+ divided by the proportion of people aged 15-64 in a population.  Or equivalently, it is the number of people aged 65+ divided by the number of people aged 15-64 in a population.